# Catch user referral via Requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

What's the best way to catch the referring user to an application (via apprequests dialogue)

Answer (score 1):

When a user come to your app via a request the url has the field 'request_ids'. Catch from that:

```
$_GET['request_ids']
```

Also remember that you will have to manually delete these app requests once accepted.